# Minecraft crashing after world load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[12:38:47] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: sean464
[12:38:50] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[12:38:50] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[12:38:52] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[12:38:53] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[12:38:53] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[12:38:53] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[12:38:53] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[12:38:54] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[12:38:57] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[12:39:10] [Client thread/INFO]: Deleting level New World--
[12:39:10] [Client thread/INFO]: Attempt 1...
[12:39:12] [Client thread/INFO]: Deleting level New World-
[12:39:12] [Client thread/INFO]: Attempt 1...
[12:39:14] [Client thread/INFO]: Deleting level New World
[12:39:14] [Client thread/INFO]: Attempt 1...
[12:39:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.10.1
[12:39:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[12:39:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[12:39:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 4%
[12:39:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 6%
[12:39:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 10%
[12:39:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 13%
[12:39:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 18%
[12:39:26] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 22%
[12:39:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 27%
[12:39:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 31%
[12:39:29] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 36%
[12:39:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 40%
[12:39:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 45%
[12:39:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 49%
[12:39:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 52%
[12:39:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 56%
[12:39:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 60%
[12:39:37] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 65%
[12:39:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 69%
[12:39:39] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 73%
[12:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 76%
[12:39:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 80%
[12:39:42] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 84%
[12:39:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 88%
[12:39:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 92%
[12:39:45] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 96%
[12:39:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 16, from 10
[12:39:47] [Server thread/INFO]: sean464[local:E:75191748] logged in with entity id 671 at (153.5, 64.0, 178.5)
[12:39:47] [Server thread/INFO]: sean464 joined the game
[12:39:57] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 10920ms behind, skipping 218 tick(s)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff9e86d2177, pid=6572, tid=9800
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x12177]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\SeanJr\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid6572.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: Are you using mods?

Answer (score 0):

Read this part of the report:

A fatal error has been detected by         the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff9e86d2177, pid=6572, tid=9800
The most notable part is the exception: Access Violation. I'm a computer programmer, and whenever I get this error with one of my games (actually happened yesterday, strangest glitch ever...), it means that the program is trying to read a file it's not allowed to access. 
In short, Minecraft is trying to read a file it's not allowed to read. 
Is this in single-player mode? If it's on a server, it may mean that the server is trying to access some files (credit card info, phone numbers, etc.) and Minecraft crashed to protect you from this. Otherwise, make sure that you haven't tampered with any of the Minecraft files... and report this to Mojang. Also make sure that you aren't on version 1.10.1, as it caused a lot of errors. 
Hope this helps!